# window.open with ampersands in uri

Tags: javascript

Been searching and cant find a working answer.

I have the following code, But it seems to stop after the first ampersand.
I cant figure out how to send it via a window.open. the encodeURI function does nothing.

Any ideas?

JS:

```
var ref = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);

function openPage(id,name,os1)
{

url = 'http://example.com/index.php?id='+id+'&os1='+os1;

// Open window.
window.open(url,name,"toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=470px,height=400px");
// End.
}
```

The problem is URL = ( http://example.com/index.php?id=Blaa )
Rather than
http://example.com/index.php?id=Blaa&os1=Foo

It seems to stop at the ampersand. I cant see how to use it properly. Im clearly being stuipd here.

Any ideas?

Thanks
GH

Comment: ensure that you are indeed passing all the params. Ran your code in console with `openPage("fred","NameME","joe")` and it opens a page with both params in the url.

Comment: Hmm, Even if i manually set them, it just stops after id=blaa  .. It doesnt include the rest.

Comment: I agree with scrappedcola, your code as is works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/dLxvvzdc/

Comment: Waaaa lol. This is really strange.. I run it locally, It doesntw ork and fails befor ethe ampersand, yet on JSfiddle, it works.....

How is possible . Oh my god. Im going to explode in frustration here. Something so simple has broken me tonight.

Must be something myend then.. What the.